# What is the correct method of performing an 'Or' operation in an 'If' Statement? - Python

Tags: python

I have an If staement that is not behaving as I would have intended.

Here is my example:

```
if not userTime[-2].upper() == "X" or not userTime[-2].upper() == "Z":
        raise ValueError("not entered an X or a Z")
else:
        notValid = False
```

My input would always result in `userTime[-2]` always being a capital 'Z'

Printing out the `userTime[-2].upper()` to the screen appears as a 'Z' Yet it still raises the exception.

I cannot get it to hit the `else` part of this 'if' statement and am now wondering if there is something I have missed out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The opposite of `a or b` isn't `not a or not b`, it's `not a and not b`. Try:

```
if not userTime[-2].upper() == "X" and not userTime[-2].upper() == "Z":
```

Or, equivalently,

```
if userTime[-2].upper() != "X" and userTime[-2].upper() != "Z":
```

Or, avoiding the issue of complex boolean expressions entirely,

```
if userTime[-2].upper() not in ("X", "Z"):
```

Negating boolean expressions is a bit counterintuitive. Consult [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) for more information.

Comment: You probably want to use `!=` instead of `not .. ==` as well.

Comment: Dang it Kevin, you added `not in` to your answer, which I was going to add as an answer of my own... right before I added mine. Curses!

Comment: There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.

Comment: @AviahLaor: `if usertime[-2].casefold() not in "xz": raise ValueError("not entered an X or a Z (ignoring case)")` seems obvious (for a reader).